# Customize error message from default validation methods rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's a strange problem I needed help with.

So I'm trying to validate the checkboxes in my form so that atleast one has to be selected:

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:topping_ids, Topping.all, :id, :name, include_hidden: false) do |b| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= b.check_box %> - <%= b.label %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
...
```

My Model:

```
class Pizza < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pizza_toppings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :toppings, through: :pizza_toppings

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_length_of :topping_ids, minimum: 1, message: "You must select at least 1 topping"
end
```

My error partial:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="errors-alert text-center">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li class="errors-alert-item text-center"><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is what the error looks like:

[image: snapshot]

How do I change or get rid of that "Topping ids" in the error. I learned how to change the message but I'm not sure what I would change for "Toppings ids", it obviously provides no use to the user. I don't want to change the error complete from locals or anything like that because I used validations for other forms so I want to be able to see those errors, this is the only one I need to modify for.

Comment: you have to provide the name alternative in the locals file for the specific attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use locales for custom error messages.

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      pizza:
        topping_ids: ""
```

You will need to override the attribute name.

But remember the attribute name will not be displayed anywhere when you use

```
errors.full_messages
```

Or go with `errors.messages` instead of `errors.full_messages`

Comment: Changing the specific attribute in the locales works perfectly for what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<% object.errors.values.flatten.each do |msg| %>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
<% object.errors.full_messages.each do |attr,msg| %>
  <li class="errors-alert-item text-center"><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
```

If you do instead:

```
<%= attr %> <%= msg %>
```

you get this error message with the attribute name

Comment: ah that would work but I have the error code in a partial that I want to use for multiple forms to keep my code DRY. I need the <%= attr %>  for other validations and forms so I can't completely remove it. Thanks!